# Using content values to convert string to integer

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am currently working from a project used in a tutorial that displays contacts in a listview. All the fields in the database are used and saved as strings. A custom adapter class is being used for the edit and delete buttons - the buttons appear on the listview, per item. Clicking on edit leads to a separate activity to in which details for that record are parsed in.

I have added another button that I'd like to update a record when clicked and reload the activity. When you press the button it calls a method from the `connector` method:

```
    public void updateContact(long id, String name, String phone, String mail,
        String fb, byte[] blob) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(Contacts.NAME, name);
    cv.put(Contacts.PHONE, phone);
    cv.put(Contacts.MAIL, mail);
    cv.put(Contacts.FB, fb);
    cv.put(Contacts.IMAGE, blob);

    db = sqlHp.getWritableDatabase();
    db.update(Contacts.TABLE, cv, Contacts.ID + "=" + id, null);
    db.close();
}
```

I would like `phone` to convert the string to an integer, increment the value by 1 and then save using contentvalues as a string. Here is what I've tried:

```
    public void updateContact(long id, String name, String phone,
        String mail, String fb, byte[] blob) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(Contacts.NAME, name);
    int phone1 = 0;
    phone1 = (Integer) cv.getAsInteger(Contacts.PHONE);

        phone1++;


        phone = String.valueOf(phone1);

        cv.put(Contacts.PHONE, phone);


    cv.put(Contacts.MAIL, mail);
    cv.put(Contacts.FB, fb);
    cv.put(Contacts.IMAGE, blob);

    db = sqlHp.getWritableDatabase();
    db.update(Contacts.TABLE, cv, Contacts.ID + "=" + id, null);
    db.close();
}
```

This gives me a `null pointer exception` error. I'm not sure where to go from here.

This is the method from the custom adapter which holds the onclick method

```
    setPresent = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.setPresent);
    setPresent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            sqlCon.updateContact(id, name, phone, email,  fb, image);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyContactsActivity.class)
                    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }

    });
```

It's when I click this button the null pointer exception error occurs. These are the lines it flags up:

```
                sqlCon.updateContact(id, name, phone, email,  fb, image);
```

- from the customadapter

and

```
        phone1 = (Integer) cv.getAsInteger(Contacts.PHONE);
```

- from the connector

Comment: Which line throws the `NullPointerException`? Can you please post the error from LogCat?

Comment: it's the line 'phone1 = (Integer) cv.getAsInteger(Contacts.PHONE);'

I will update the post with the logcat error(s)

Comment: One definite problem here is that you are declaring a set of `new ContentValues();` and then trying to get the value `Contacts.PHONE` when it is clear that nothing has been added at that point. It's possible that that could be your error.

Comment: You are creating a new cv...then you try to geht a value...it's null obviously, as you didn't put anything in before...edit: too slow on phone

Comment: so instead of doing this in the connector class it would be best to convert to int and increment in another class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part doesn't really make sense in your code:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
int phone1 = (Integer) cv.getAsInteger(Contacts.PHONE);
```

You are trying to get `Contacts.PHONE` from a `ContentValues` you just created.

Perhaps you wanted to do something like this instead:

```
cv.put(Contacts.PHONE, Integer.parseInt(phone) + 1);
```

If you clean up this part, the `NullPointerException` will probably disappear naturally.

Also, it's safer to update tables using `?` placeholders for parameters instead of puttin them in the query string, like this:

```
db.update(Contacts.TABLE, cv, Contacts.ID + " = ?", new long[]{id});
```

Comment: Ah, I am indeed using my new `ContentValues` incorrectly. I'm going to keep the field as a string in the database but have the string in the textveiw convert to int, ++, and then save it's contents.